# Printing a message that element is not present in catch block, selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

This is my Feature file:

```
@Done @ProdSmoke @KioskSmoke
Scenario Outline: Add Items to the Cart and click Cancel
  Given Open the application on Tablet device
  When Click on the KeyInItem button
  Then Enter Item Number "<upc>"
  And Click Cancel
  And Item "not added" in the cart
  Examples:
    | upctype | upc|
    | upca    | 8 |
```

This is my stepdef file:

```
 @And("^Item \"([^\"]*)\" in the cart$")
 public void itemAddedInTheCart(String action) throws Exception {
    addItem.verify_itemadded(action);
}
```

And this is my function verify_itemadded(action):

```
public void verify_itemadded(String action) throws Exception {

    try {
        if (action.equals("added") && element("ItemVerify").isDisplayed()) {
            Assert.assertTrue(element("ItemVerify").isDisplayed());
            logger.info("Item Added");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if(action.equals("not added") && !element("ItemVerify").isDisplayed())
            logger.info("Item not added");
    }
}
```

Even though the test is passing, I am unable to get the message "item not added".

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, the condition is evaluated to false, in `if (action.equals("added") && element("ItemVerify").isDisplayed())`. Because of it, exception is never thrown. Why do you keep the 'not added' case in the catch block anyway?

Comment: @Jonah If assert is failed then it will throw AssertionError and that is the reason why he has added that code in the exception block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the code as below. Let me know if you face any issue.

```
try
{
    boolean isItemVerified = element("ItemVerify").isDisplayed());
    if (action.equals("added") && isItemVerified ) 
    {
        logger.info("Item Added");
    }
     Assert.assertTrue(isItemVerified);
 }
 catch(AssertionError ae)
 {
     logger.info("Item not added");
 }
```